# Site multilíngua

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando colocar um site feito em Python/Django como multilíngua, porém não consegui entender como fazer de fato com a documentação ou o que encontrei na Internet, inclusive encontrei um aqui no próprio StackOverflow Inglês e também não entendi muito bem.
Alguém poderia me ajudar

Como exemplo gostaria de ter:

```
meusite.com/pt
meusite.com/en
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que precisa, você já tem os sites e precisa faze-los funcionar ou quer saber como fazer sites multilíngua?

Comment: Tenho site já em português, estou precisando fazer com ele tenha sua versão em ingles e receba no fim da url /en

Comment: Rapaz esse tema é meio extenso pra tratar aqui, mas pra iniciar procure no google sobre htaccess que faz o direcionamento das paginas e no index.php (se tiver usando php, claro) você deverá fazer as devidas implementações dos includes e translators, você pode usar duas composições de páginas cada uma com sua linguagem ou pode usar ferramentas como php-gettext e por ai vai...

Comment: Ha, desculpe não ter citado, mas o site é em python-django, só coloquei a tag na pergunta. Acabei de arrumar a pergunta.

Comment: Então, eu faço em PHP, ma a lógica é a mesma, você terá que usar ferramentas pra isso ou criar os sites em liguagens diferentes e redirecionar para a página que precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Então, como você não postou seu código, vou botar um super básico baseado no Django 2.0.x

No seu arquivo `settings.py`, você precisa definir os seguintes valores:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
USE_I18N = True
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('pt-br', 'Português'),
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # outras definições
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # outras definições
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

Agora, no seu arquivo `urls.py` deve conter:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # todas as suas urls aqui que NÃO precisam do prefixo do prefixo de idioma
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    # AQUI entram suas urls que precisam do prefixo de idioma
)
```

Esse é o super básico. Espero que sirva.

Comment: Obrigado, assim que eu testar dou um feedback se consegui.